# vs2010 watch window : print out some member to parent node

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, window, watch

first of all, see the screenshot please.

[image]

this is a watch window of vs 2010.

i want to some sub member of structure/class move up into parent's value field for easier debugging. (in C#)

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a DebuggerDisplay attribute above your MeanItem class.  Something like:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Content={Content}")]
public class MeanItem
{
...
```

The value between the {} is the name of the property you want to display in the debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for classes you're writing.

Use the `DebuggerDisplay` attribute:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("N: {Name}; A1: {Address1}; A2: {Address2}; C: {City}; S: {State}; Z: {ZipCode}; P: {Phone}; F: {Fax}")]
internal class EntityAddress
{
...
}
```

Or for your simpler usage:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Content}")]
class MeanItem
{
...
}
```

Where each of the bracketed items are properties on the object. The string created with this attribute will show exactly as you're wanting.

MSDN Documentation: [Using DebuggerDisplay Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x810d419.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the source for the MeanItem class? If so, you can override the ToString() method to return the value of MeanItem.Content - that should make it show up (instead of UOC.DicData.MeanItem).

Comment: This breaks if you're expecting a different, specific `ToString()` behavior elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The area you point to in your example is just the `ToString` representation of an object (which, by default, shows the class name).

You could override ToString in your class and return Content

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return Content;
}
```

Comment: This breaks if you're expecting a different, specific `ToString()` behavior elsewhere.

Comment: @BQ - Absolutely, without a doubt the `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` is the way to go. Ive left this here as an alternate.

Comment: @Jaimec, not a problem. This works fine in most cases. Except when it doesn't, it REALLY doesn't. Left the comment just so someone doesn't choose to do this thinking they're equivalent or that this is easier.